Nikon D90 shutter gets stuck with a lens on, but works fine with no lens. How do I fix this?
I recently experienced my D90's shutter get stuck when I take photos. When I removed the lens, the shutter works perfect. I also realized that the shutter works with the lens fitted 95% on, untill it clips in...
I have Googled and read articles, and have tried the following with no success:

Changed and charged batteries
Changed and checked SD cards
Oiled/ lubricated the shutter arm
cleaned the lens and camera connection points, and all around
Changed lenses
Switched in and out of Live mode
Changed settings back to factory settings
Switched between modes A, P, M, S

I saw a post of 19 months ago with the same problem, but could not find that the person found a solution. Any additional information or advice will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I can't help you directly, but thank you for writing a clear question where you have clearly done your research and tried the obvious things before posting here.

Are you certain it is the shutter and not the mirror that is getting stuck?
On many/most Nikons the mechanism that moves the mirror also opens the lens' aperture. It sounds to me like that lever in the camera body is slightly bent and getting jammed when the lens is fully installed. If the mirror cannot fully cycle it will prevent an image from being taken.
The lever in question is circled in this picture. Check that it is undamaged and moves freely top to bottom.

And this Nikon Support Article discusses the bent lever issue in some detail; although it does not mention the mirror binding.
